# how to 'unhook/unbind' some js when toggling with .click

Tags: jquery, slider, toggleclass, unbind

I've a slider that works really well but when I click something in the slider I want the slider to stop working.
At the moment I have

```
$("#slider").GenericSlider({
  mode: "horizontal",
  animation: "CSS",
  marginStart: "300",
  marginEnd: "0",
  infinite: "true"
});
```

but I want this to stop and restart when I do this

```
$(".samuel").click(function () {
  $(".samuel").toggleClass("show-bio");
});
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: We cannot answer this without your slider code..

Comment: it's the paid for version of this - http://www.flowslider.com/ - I was hoping you could just say 'when this is clicked turn this off' - is that not possible?

Comment: http://www.flowslider.com/for-developers/api-html/methods -- Have you tried the `start()` and `stop()` methods?

Comment: How do I call that method? like this? $("#slider").FlowSlider.stop();